# Why can't I generate user token in Instagram API?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to use instagram api to show #'s on my webpage but i need to generate user token for instagram tester. I followed the documentatio (created an application, use my page url, sent invitation for instagram tester and accepted it) but when i click on generate token for instagram tester it displays a pop-up window to allow permissions, then it shows nothing. I tried with another account, creating a different application but the result is the same.

[image: allow permissions]

[image: blank]

Comment: Hi, if you solved the problem can you please tell us what was it, thanks ❤️

Comment: i'm looking for another options because can't find the solution anywhere

Comment: If you find anything, Please tell me

Comment: I've got the same error. It's during the final OAuth2 stage in which the token generator should issue an access_token with the authorization code. Maybe try finishing the OAuth2 process using Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook token generator seems to be broken, but you can generate your own long-lived access token following OAuth2 workflow (replace `{}` placeholders with your own values):

1. In your browser, go to:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={your-client-id}&client_secret={your-client-secret}&redirect_uri={a-valid-redirect-url}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code
```

2. Login to your Instagram account and accept your application to access your data
3. You should be redirected to `{a-valid-redirect-url}?code=xxxxx#_` then copy to {code} query string value without the `#_` at the end
4. Use Postman to execute a `POST` request to  `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` with `x-www-form-urlencoded` params

   - `client_id`: {your-client-id}
   - `client_secret`: {your-client-secret}
   - `grant_type`: authorization_code
   - `redirect_uri`: {a-valid-redirect-url}
   - `code`: {the code you extracted from query string}
5. You should get a short-lived access-token response such as:

```json
{
    "access_token": "IGQVxxxxxxxxxx…",
    "user_id": xxxxxxxxxx
}
```

6. Exchange your short-lived access-token with a long-lived one: use Postman to execute a `GET` request to `https://graph.instagram.com/access_token` with query params:

   - `client_id`: {your-client-id}
   - `client_secret`: {your-client-secret}
   - `grant_type`: ig_exchange_token
   - `access_token`: {the short-lived access_token}
7. You should get a long-lived access-token response such as:

```json
{
    "access_token": "IGQxxxxx…",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 5169852
}
```

Comment: I got some errors first but now it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: what does "expires_in" mean, do i have a limited time to use this token? does it refear to hours, mins?

Comment: Long-lived tokens are limited to 60 days. You will have to refresh them. You should have enough activity on your API too because Facebook could disable your App due to inactivity.

Comment: i got error on point 4 step
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "This authorization code has been used"
}